# Would someone let me know what is wrong with the XSL below?

Tags: xml, xslt

I created this xslt mapping using Contivo but it's not working for the XML below.
Would someone be able to identify what is wrong, please?

I spent some time already working on it but was not able to figure out what is wrong.

Here is the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- IMPORTANT: If this transform will be run using Xalan, then version 2.5.1 or higher is required. -->
<!-- Copyright (c) 2008 Contivo, Inc. All Rights Reserved.-->
<!-- NOTE: DataPower supports the Xalan:nodeset() function. -->
<!-- This transform was created by Analyst version 3.11.2.2. -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
     xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions"
     xmlns:ctvf="http://www.contivo.com/xslt/extensions"
     xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
     xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions"
     xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Inventory.Data.Models"
     xmlns:xs2="http://integration.com/interfaces/queryDirectInventory/v1/queryDirectInventory.xsd"
     extension-element-prefixes="func ctvf date dp"
     exclude-result-prefixes="xalan tns s">

    <xsl:variable name='_root' select='/'/>
    <xsl:template match='/'>
        <xsl:variable name="__MappingResults">
        <xsl:value-of select="ctvf:trim($_root//tns:InventoryInquiryApiResponse[1]/tns:InventoryInquiryApiResult[1]/tns:SkuAvailabilities[1]/tns:SkuAvailabilityResponse[1]/tns:AvailabilityIndicator[1])"/>
            <e>
                <xsl:attribute name="n">xs2:queryDirectInventoryResponse</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="m">t</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="d">f</xsl:attribute>
                <e>
                    <xsl:attribute name="n">xs2:availabilityList</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="m">t</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="d">f</xsl:attribute>
                    <e>
                        <xsl:attribute name="n">xs2:availabilityList</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="m">t</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="d">f</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="m">l</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$_root//tns:InventoryInquiryApiResponse[1]/tns:InventoryInquiryApiResult[1]/tns:SkuAvailabilities[1]/tns:SkuAvailabilityResponse">
                            <e>
                                <xsl:attribute name="n">xs2:availabilityList</xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:attribute name="m">f</xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:attribute name="d">f</xsl:attribute>
                                <e>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="n">xs2:availabilityInd</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="m">f</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="d">f</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="ctvf:trim(string(./tns:AvailabilityIndicator[1]))"/>
                                </e>
                                <e>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="n">xs2:availableQuantity</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="m">f</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="d">f</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="ctvf:testForNullNumber(./tns:AvailableQuantity[1], &quot;&quot;)"/>
                                </e>
                                <e>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="n">xs2:zipCode</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="m">f</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="d">f</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="ctvf:trim(./tns:PostalCode[1])"/>
                                </e>
                                <e>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="n">xs2:itemId</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="m">f</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="d">f</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="ctvf:trim(./tns:Sku[1])"/>
                                </e>
                                <e>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="n">xs2:statusMessageInfo</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="m">f</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="d">f</xsl:attribute>
                                    <e>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="n">xs2:statusMessageCode</xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="m">t</xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="d">f</xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="ctvf:trim(./tns:StatusMessage[1])"/>
                                    </e>
                                    <e>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="n">xs2:statusMessageText</xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="m">f</xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="d">f</xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="ctvf:convertNumber(ctvf:trim(string(./tns:StatusMessageCode[1])))"/>
                                    </e>
                                </e>
                            </e>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <e>
                            <xsl:attribute name="n">xs2:availabilityList</xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="m">t</xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="d">f</xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="m">e</xsl:attribute>
                            <e>
                                <xsl:attribute name="n">xs2:statusMessageInfo</xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:attribute name="m">f</xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:attribute name="d">f</xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:attribute name="m">e</xsl:attribute>
                                <e>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="n">xs2:statusMessageCode</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="m">t</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="d">f</xsl:attribute>
                                </e>
                            </e>
                        </e>
                    </e>
                </e>
            </e>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:apply-templates select='xalan:nodeset($__MappingResults)' mode="eliminateEmptyTags"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a" mode="eliminateEmptyTags">
        <xsl:if test='@v != "" or @m = "t"'>
            <xsl:attribute name="{@n}">
                <xsl:value-of select='@v' />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="e" mode="eliminateEmptyTags">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test='@m = "f"'>
                <xsl:if test='descendant-or-self::*[text() != ""][@d = "f"][1]/text() != "" or descendant-or-self::a[@v != ""][@d = "f"][1]/@v != ""'>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test='@n !=""'>
                            <xsl:element name="{@n}">
                                <xsl:apply-templates select='a' mode="eliminateEmptyTags"/>
                                <xsl:value-of select='text()' />
                                <xsl:for-each select='./namespace::*'>
                                    <xsl:copy/>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select='e' mode="eliminateEmptyTags"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select='e' mode="eliminateEmptyTags"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test='@m = "l"'>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test='child::e[@m != "e"]/descendant-or-self::*[text() != ""][@d = "f"][1]/text() != "" or child::e[@m != "e"]/descendant-or-self::a[@v != ""][@d = "f"][1]/@v != ""'>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select='e[@m != "e"]' mode="eliminateEmptyTags"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select='e[@m = "e"]' mode="eliminateEmptyTags"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test='@n !=""'>
                        <xsl:element name="{@n}">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select='a' mode="eliminateEmptyTags"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select='text()' />
                            <xsl:for-each select='./namespace::*'>
                                <xsl:copy/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select='e' mode="eliminateEmptyTags"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select='e' mode="eliminateEmptyTags"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>


    <!--=========================================================================-->

    <xsl:template name="trimAll">
        <xsl:param name="trimMe"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($trimMe, ' ')">
                <xsl:call-template name="trimAll">
                    <xsl:with-param name="trimMe">
                        <xsl:value-of select='concat(substring-before($trimMe, " "), substring-after($trimMe, " "))'/>
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select='$trimMe'/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="trimLeft">
        <xsl:param name="trimMe"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="starts-with($trimMe, ' ')">
                <xsl:call-template name="trimLeft">
                    <xsl:with-param name="trimMe" select='substring-after($trimMe, " ")'/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select='$trimMe'/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="trimRight">
        <xsl:param name="trimMe"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="substring($trimMe, string-length($trimMe), 1) = ' '">
                <xsl:call-template name="trimRight">
                    <xsl:with-param name="trimMe" select='substring($trimMe, 1, string-length($trimMe) - 1)'/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select='$trimMe'/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="trimBoth">
        <xsl:param name="trimMe"/>
        <xsl:variable name="result">
            <xsl:call-template name="trimRight">
                <xsl:with-param name="trimMe" select='$trimMe'/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="resultb">
            <xsl:call-template name="trimLeft">
                <xsl:with-param name="trimMe" select='$result'/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select='$resultb'/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--=========================================================================-->

    <func:function name="ctvf:testForNullNumber">
        <xsl:param name="node"/>
        <xsl:param name="defaultValue"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="local-name($node) = ''">
                <func:result select="$defaultValue"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="string-length(normalize-space(string($node))) = 0">
                <func:result select="$defaultValue"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <func:result select="number($node)"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </func:function>

    <!--=========================================================================-->
    <func:function name="ctvf:convertNumber">
        <xsl:param name="val"/>
        <xsl:variable name="strVal" select="string($val)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$strVal = 'NaN'">
                <func:result select="''"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <func:result select="$strVal"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </func:function>

    <!--=========================================================================-->

    <func:function name="ctvf:trim">
        <xsl:param name="param" select="''"/>
        <xsl:variable name="in" select="string($param)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="len" select="string-length($in)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$len &gt; 0 and (ctvf:isWhitespace(substring($in, 1, 1)) or ctvf:isWhitespace(substring($in, $len)))">
                <xsl:variable name="first" select="ctvf:doTrimGetFirst($in, 1, $len)"/>
                <func:result select="substring($in, $first, ctvf:doTrimGetLast($in, $len, $len) - $first + 1)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <func:result select="$in"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </func:function>

    <func:function name="ctvf:isWhitespace">
        <xsl:param name="char"/>
        <func:result select="$char = '&#x20;' or $char = '&#x9;' or $char = '&#xD;' or $char = '&#xA;'"/>
    </func:function>

    <func:function name="ctvf:doTrimGetFirst">
        <xsl:param name="in"/>
        <xsl:param name="index"/>
        <xsl:param name="len"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="($index &lt;= $len) and ($index &lt;= 350) and ctvf:isWhitespace(substring($in, $index, 1))">
                <func:result select="ctvf:doTrimGetFirst($in, $index + 1, $len)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <func:result select="$index"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </func:function>

    <func:function name="ctvf:doTrimGetLast">
        <xsl:param name="in"/>
        <xsl:param name="index"/>
        <xsl:param name="len"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="($index &gt;= 1) and ($len - $index &lt;= 350) and ctvf:isWhitespace(substring($in, $index, 1))">
                <func:result select="ctvf:doTrimGetLast($in, $index - 1, $len)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <func:result select="$index"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </func:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is XML:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <InventoryInquiryApiResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <InventoryInquiryApiResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Inventory.Data.Models" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:SkuAvailabilities>
          <a:SkuAvailabilityResponse>
            <a:AvailabilityIndicator>true</a:AvailabilityIndicator>
            <a:AvailableQuantity>1</a:AvailableQuantity>
            <a:PostalCode>12065</a:PostalCode>
            <a:Sku>sku</a:Sku>
            <a:StatusMessage>OK</a:StatusMessage>
            <a:StatusMessageCode>200</a:StatusMessageCode>
          </a:SkuAvailabilityResponse>
        </a:SkuAvailabilities>
      </InventoryInquiryApiResult>
    </InventoryInquiryApiResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please don't tell us that something "doesn't work" without telling us how it fails. An experienced user can solve it in 10 seconds if you quote the error message, but will take about 3 minutes if you don't. (Moreover, they might get it wrong, as below, if you introduce additional errors in the course of posting your sample).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be (and probably are) various things wrong with your XSL. The first thing that jumps to the eye (**after** removing the undeclared `s` prefix from the `exclude-result-prefixes` list)  is that you're not using the correct namespaces of the source XML.

For example, in your very first selection:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ctvf:trim($_root//tns:InventoryInquiryApiResponse[1]/tns:InventoryInquiryApiResult[1]/tns:SkuAvailabilities[1]/tns:SkuAvailabilityResponse[1]/tns:AvailabilityIndicator[1])"/>
```

you are using the same `tns:` prefix for all your location steps - but in your XML, both `InventoryInquiryApiResponse` and `InventoryInquiryApiResult` are in the `xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"` namespace, which isn't even declared in your stylesheet. So you are starting off with your `$__MappingResults` variable being empty.

AFAICS, this mistake is repeated throughout your stylesheet, so that none of your instructions are selecting anything.

Comment: michael, are the exclude-result-prefixes used when I don't want a namespace included in the result xml? simple like this?

Answer (score 1):

You have not declared the namespace "s" in the XSL. THat is already an error if you open the XSL in an editor and you have exclude-result-prefixes="xalan tns s".

Comment: I added the s namespace to test, but missed to remove from: exclude-result-prefixes, even without it is not working. Any other idea? Thanks!

Comment: What is the definition of "not working?" what is the errors or what results are you getting that is not expected?

Comment: Oh and sorry that was the wrong thing that is wrong with your stylesheet. At least it was one thing that was wrong.